# Is video intelligence API of google cloud service available for android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

I couldn't find any SDK for Google cloud video intelligence API. 
If there is only REST API support then how can we upload video in REST API?

Searched a lot on google documentation, didn't find the proper implementation for android apps

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for the REST API: https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1/videos/annotate

You can send the video as bytes in inputContent or upload the video to GCS and then call video intelligence api with inputUri specified.

You can get the result via [GetOperation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.operations/get) or just have the result stored in GCS if you specify outputUri.